# Why is Rollup plugin loading correctly via local file but not using NPM library?

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple [Rollup plugin](https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-sass-shadow) I made. This works great if I run with the following import (using local relative)...

```
import { SassShadow } from '../../../rollup-sass-shadow/index.mjs';
```

But when I try to run with the npm version like this...

```
import { SassShadow } from '@jrg/rollup-sass-shadow';
```

I get...

```
[!] TypeError: defaultLoader is not a function
TypeError: defaultLoader is not a function
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Is your `type` set to `"module"` in `package.json`?

Comment: Thank you but I already had that. It seems the answer is more devious than I thought and probably a bug in Rollup.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to use the default export instead of the named export. So instead of...

```
 export class SassShadow{...}

 import { SassShadow } from '@jrg/rollup-sass-shadow';
```

It needed to be...

```
 class SassShadow{...}
 export default SassShadow

 import SassShadow from '@jrg/rollup-sass-shadow'
```